# Mirtoolbox miraudio function issue

Tags: matlab, audio, audio-recording, spectral

How do I solve this error?

```
a = miraudio('tea')
```

Here are the error message returned by each reader:

> Error using wavread (line 7)
>   WAVREAD will be removed in a future release. Use AUDIOREAD instead.
>   Error using auread (line 8)
>   AUREAD will be removed in a future release. Use AUDIOREAD instead.
>   Error using mp3read>mysystem (line 306)
>   unable to execute "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\toolbox\mirtoolbox1.3.3\mirtoolbox\mp3info.exe" -r m -p "%Q %u %b %r %v * %C %e %E %L %O %o %p" "tea.mp3" (Error opening MP3: tea.mp3: No such file or directory
>   )
>   Error using aiffread (line 159)
>   Could not open file 'tea.aif'.
>   Error using mirerror (line 4)
>   ERROR using MIRREAD: Cannot open file tea
>
> Error in mirread>misread (line 142)
>   mirerror('MIRREAD',['Cannot open file ',file]);
>
> Error in mirread (line 57)
>                           misread(orig, err);
>
> Error in mireval (line 68)
>       [d1,tp1,fp1,f1,lg,b,n,ch] = mirread([],file,0,0,0);
>
> Error in mirfunction (line 69)
>               o = mireval(o,filename,nout);
>
> Error in miraudio (line 170)
>       varargout = mirfunction(@miraudio,orig,varargin,nargout,specif,@init,@main);

Comment: `Error opening MP3: tea.mp3: No such file or directory` Does the file exist? Maybe try full path instead of relative path.

Comment: The file did exist and it's path was set to matlab. The problem is solved by using the later version of MIRtoolbox (1.6.1), the version used previously was 1.3.3 and it has error reading audio files. Thanks anyway!